# Azure DB - Mssql - PHP mssql_fetch_assoc timing out question

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, query-optimization

Did a database migration to Azure from 2008 dedicated server. It was working before and was slow but now this bit of code seems to be timing out and not sure why. If i manually run the query on Sqlserver returns about 5200 results, runtime about 1 seconds. No query errors - overview on azure dashboard doesn't seem to be going over DTU rate.  If i narrow down to just a couple results that bit of code below works. Any suggestion or more information I can add here to help get this problem solved? I need need all the information from the Select *.

Edit: added more information - working on getting the plans. not sure why table formatting isn't showing right. Shows correctly in the editing view. Added photos.

```
query 

SELECT
    at.*, u.username as activity_username
FROM
    activity_track as at
LEFT JOIN
        ccusers u
        ON
            at.activity_userid = u.ccusersid
WHERE
    (activity_action='Edit Attorney Sales Rep' OR activity_action='Edit Attorney Referral Source')
ORDER BY
    at.activity_date DESC
```

activity_track table def -- row count 514347

- activity_id - int - PK
- activity_server_info  - text
- activity_userid - big int
- activity_date - datetime
- activity_action_type - varchar(25)
- activity_action - varchar(50)
- activity_notes - text

ccusers -- def row count 1281807

- username - varchar(50)
- password - varchar(50)
- ccUsersid - bigint - PK
- user_type - varchar(50)
- agencies - varchar (50)
- c_date - varchar(50)
- isEmp - tinyint

ccusers

- IX_c_date    nonclustered    c_date
- IX_counselingagencies    nonclustered    counselingAgencies
- IX_isDecafemployee   nonclustered    isDecafEmployee
- IX_password  nonclustered    password
- IX_user_type nonclustered    user_type
- IX_username  nonclustered    username
- PK_ccUsers   clustered, unique,    primary key   ccUsersId

activity_track

- IX_activity_track    nonclustered    activity_date
- IX_activity_track_1  nonclustered    activity_userid
- IX_activity_track_2  nonclustered    activity_action_type
- IX_activity_track_3  nonclustered    activity_action
- PK_activity_track    clustered, unique, primary key  activity_id

```
$result = mssql_query ( $query, $website_database_connection );
while ( $row = mssql_fetch_assoc ( $result ) )
    {
        $Activities [ ] = $row;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241429/discussion-on-question-by-quickee-azure-db-mssql-php-mssql-fetch-assoc-timin).

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your php program to use the [`sqlsrv_` API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php); it's the "official" way to get from php to SQL Server.

Then, let's take this optimization step by step.

First: try this simplified query.

```sql
SELECT at.activity_id
  FROM activity_track as at
 WHERE (    at.activity_action='Edit Attorney Sales Rep'
         OR at.activity_action='Edit Attorney Referral Source')
 ORDER BY at.activity_date DESC
```

That *should* be made reasonably fast by your index on `activity_track (activity_action)`. The plan should show a nonclustered index seek with two iterations, one for each value. It looks like you're filtering  about 10% of the rows in that table.  *If it still shows nonclustered index scan*, it's possible there are so few different values in `activity_action` that the optimizer concludes a full scan is faster. It seems unlikely given the ~10% filtering.

Then try `SELECT at.*` instead of `SELECT at.activity_id`. You should keep most of your performance.

Finally, add back the left join to `ccusers`.

**Pro tip**: avoid `SELECT *` especially when you're having performance trouble. Instead, enumerate the columns you need from the table.

If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: I read that PDO vs sqlsrv there isn't much a different under the hood. The app is.. i dunno 50 million lines of code?? and it looks the objects return are a little different between the two. Im not sure this is an option. Were you referring to running these queries from the app or on SSMS? .. ive ran the query you suggested with the Execution Plan and it didn't not make any recommendation. I posted those outputs in the comments above. Copied and pasted into SSMS its fast < 1s, from the app its slow. Removing the left join from the app its still times out AND without the OR.

Comment: ```SELECT
 at.activity_id
FROM
 activity_track2 as at
WHERE
 activity_action='Edit Attorney Sales Rep'
ORDER BY
 at.activity_date DESC
```